# Updating a string field by concatenating 2 int columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, update, concat

I have 2 columns, an `int` and a `tiny int`, and I want to update another column, a `varchar` one, with the value `column1 + '-' + column2`. Something like this pseudo code:

```
UPDATE COLUMN3 varchar = CONCAT (COLUMN1 INT AND + COLUMN2 TINYINT);
```

How can I do it with real code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to reference your table. [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function will handle conversions between `INT` and `TINY INT`.

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET Column3 = CONCAT(Column1, '-', Column2)
```

`NULL` values are treated as empty strings (`''`) with `CONCAT`. If you want to filter out these records add `IS NOT NULL` as `WHERE` condition.

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET Column3 = CONCAT(Column1, '-', Column2) 
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL
```

You can also do explicit conversion to `VARCHAR`, but keep in mind that any `NULL` values concatenated this way (with `+`) will yield a `NULL` result.

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET 
    Column3 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Column1) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Column2)
```